# Subset data frame based on non matching value in a columns

Tags: r, dataframe, dplyr, group-by

I have a dataframe as below

```
year district
2017 arrah
2017 buxar
2017 rohtas
2018 rohtas
2018 arwal
2018 seohar
2019 nawda
2019 buxar
2019 jamui
```

I want to subset data in a way that repeated district in 2018 or 2019 should not appear in the subset as shown below

```
year district
2017 arrah
2017 buxar
2017 rohtas
2018 arwal
2018 seohar
2019 nawda
2019 jamui
```

I have tried `anti_join` function but it is not solving my problem.

Comment: Please specify which of the rows and why should stay in the subset. For instance why have you chosen `2017 buxar` instead of `2019 buxar`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

## dplyr

```r
library(dplyr)
quux %>%
  group_by(district) %>%
  slice_min(year) %>%
  ungroup()
# # A tibble: 7 x 2
#    year district
#   <int> <chr>   
# 1  2017 arrah   
# 2  2018 arwal   
# 3  2017 buxar   
# 4  2019 jamui   
# 5  2019 nawda   
# 6  2017 rohtas  
# 7  2018 seohar
```

## base R

```r
quux[ave(quux$year, quux$district, FUN = function(y) y == min(y)) > 0, ]
#   year district
# 1 2017    arrah
# 2 2017    buxar
# 3 2017   rohtas
# 5 2018    arwal
# 6 2018   seohar
# 7 2019    nawda
# 9 2019    jamui
```

---

Data

```r
quux <- structure(list(year = c(2017L, 2017L, 2017L, 2018L, 2018L, 2018L, 2019L, 2019L, 2019L), district = c("arrah", "buxar", "rohtas", "rohtas", "arwal", "seohar", "nawda", "buxar", "jamui")), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -9L))
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is the sample subsetting records having earliest years for every district. You may select other summarise (agregate) function:

```
library(dplyr)
df <- data.frame(
  year = c ( 
    2017, 
    2017, 
    2017,
    2018, 
    2018, 
    2018, 
    2019, 
    2019, 
    2019
  ),
  district = c (
    "arrah",
    "buxar",
    "rohtas",
    "rohtas",
    "arwal",
    "seohar",
    "nawda",
    "buxar",
    "jamui"
  )
)


df %>% group_by(district) %>% 
  summarise(year = min(year))
```

Comment: @r2evans Thank you very much. I confused the verbs. Corrected

Answer (score 0):

We can try the following `data.table` option

```
> library(data.table)

> setcolorder(setDT(df)[, .SD[which.min(year)], district], "year")[]
   year district
1: 2017    arrah
2: 2017    buxar
3: 2017   rohtas
4: 2018    arwal
5: 2018   seohar
6: 2019    nawda
7: 2019    jamui
```

Comment: Using `.I` can avoid the column ordering later `setDT(df)[df[, .I[which.min(year)], district]$V1]`

Comment: @akrun Aha, I almost forgot the magic of `.I`. Thanks a lot :)